# HTML Table: Rowspan pushing other rows to the bottom

Tags: html, html-table, row

I can't figure out how to evenly spread vertically the other rows that are shown on the right end, instead of having them pushed to the bottom as it's shown in **[this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XehRnBasPZ3fur1eprvx?p=preview)** and the image below.

[image: Image illustrating the problem]

```
<table class="nr-grid table table-condensed fs-grid feed-results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-advertiser-brand">
        <div ng-hide="isPreview" class="dropdown pull-right dropdown-toggle" dropdown="" dropdown-append-to-body="" dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter inactive" ng-class="{inactive: filter.advertiserBrand == ''}" ng-click="setFocus('advertiserBrandFilter')"></i>

        </div>
        <div class="col-label" ng-click="setSort(keyChain.advertiserBrand)">
          <i class="glyphicon pull-right glyphicon-chevron-down ng-hide" ng-show="filter.sort.column == keyChain.advertiserBrand" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-chevron-up', false: 'glyphicon-chevron-down'}[filter.sort.ascending]"></i> Advertiser
          <br>Brand
        </div>
      </th>
      <!--<th class="">
                                    <div ng-hide="isPreview" class="dropdown pull-right" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body dropdown-toggle>
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" ng-class="{inactive: filter.advertiser == ''}" ng-click="setFocus('advertiserFilter')"></i>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="text" focus-on="advertiserFilter" ng-model="filter.advertiser" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" ng-change="getFeed()" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-label" ng-click="setSort(keyChain.advertiser)">
                                        <i class="glyphicon pull-right" ng-show="filter.sort.column == keyChain.advertiser" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-chevron-up', false: 'glyphicon-chevron-down'}[filter.sort.ascending]"></i>
                                        Advertiser
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="">
                                    <div ng-hide="isPreview" class="dropdown pull-right" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body dropdown-toggle>
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" ng-class="{inactive: filter.brand == ''}" ng-click="setFocus('brandFilter')"></i>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="text" focus-on="brandFilter" ng-model="filter.brand" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" ng-change="getFeed()" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-label" ng-click="setSort(keyChain.brand)">
                                        <i class="glyphicon pull-right" ng-show="filter.sort.column == keyChain.brand" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-chevron-up', false: 'glyphicon-chevron-down'}[filter.sort.ascending]"></i>
                                        Brand
                                    </div>
                                </th>-->
      <th class="col-ad-transcript">
        Ad Transcript
      </th>
      <th class="col-region-market">
        <div ng-hide="isPreview" class="dropdown pull-right dropdown-toggle" dropdown="" dropdown-append-to-body="" dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter inactive" ng-class="{inactive: filter.regionMarket == ''}" ng-click="setFocus('regionMarketFilter')"></i>

        </div>
        <div class="col-label" ng-click="setSort(keyChain.regionMarket)">
          <i class="glyphicon pull-right glyphicon-chevron-down ng-hide" ng-show="filter.sort.column == keyChain.regionMarket" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-chevron-up', false: 'glyphicon-chevron-down'}[filter.sort.ascending]"></i> Country
          <br>Market
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="col-industry-category">
        Industry
        <br>Category
      </th>
      <th class="col-channel">
        <div ng-hide="isPreview" class="dropdown pull-right dropdown-toggle" dropdown="" dropdown-append-to-body="" dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter inactive" ng-class="{inactive: filter.channel == ''}" ng-click="setFocus('channelFilter')"></i>

        </div>
        <div class="col-label" ng-click="setSort(keyChain.channel)">
          <i class="glyphicon pull-right glyphicon-chevron-down ng-hide" ng-show="filter.sort.column == keyChain.channel" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-chevron-up', false: 'glyphicon-chevron-down'}[filter.sort.ascending]"></i> Channel
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="col-created">
        <div class="col-label" ng-click="setSort(keyChain.firstAiring)">
          <i class="glyphicon pull-right glyphicon-chevron-down" ng-show="filter.sort.column == keyChain.firstAiring" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-chevron-up', false: 'glyphicon-chevron-down'}[filter.sort.ascending]"></i> First Airing
        </div>
      </th>
      <!-- ngIf: feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
      <th class="col-play ng-scope" ng-if="feedFilter.IncludeMp3">
        Play
      </th>
      <!-- end ngIf: feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- ngRepeat: feed in feedList track by $index -->
  <tbody ng-repeat="feed in feedList track by $index" class="ng-scope">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" title="HDZ
    HDZ" class="ng-binding">
        HDZ
        <br>
        <!--</td>
                                    <td rowspan="{{feed.Channels.length + 1}}" title="{{feed.BrandName}}">-->
        HDZ
      </td>
      <td class="wrap-text ng-binding" rowspan="2" title="HDZ Brodsko-posavske cestita vam Dan Državnosti">
        HDZ Brodsko-posavske cestita vam Dan Državnosti
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" ng-attr-title="{{feed.Regions}}
    {{feed.Markets}}" title="Hrvatska
    Hrvatska, Slavonija">
        <span class="ng-binding">Hrvatska<br></span>
        <span class="ng-binding">Hrvatska, Slavonija</span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" title="Politika
    Izbori" class="ng-binding">
        Politika
        <br>Izbori
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ngRepeat: channel in feed.Channels track by $index -->
    <tr ng-repeat="channel in feed.Channels track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <td title="Radio Slavonija" class="ng-binding">
        Radio Slavonija
      </td>
      <td title="2017-06-24T07:32:32" class="ng-binding">
        24.6.2017 07:32:32
      </td>
      <!-- ngIf: $first && feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
      <td ng-if="$first &amp;&amp; feedFilter.IncludeMp3" rowspan="1" class="ng-scope">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" ng-click="playPauseSong(feed, $parent.$parent.$index)">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-pause', false: 'glyphicon-play'}[$parent.$parent.$index === player.playingInfo.uiIndentifier &amp;&amp; player.playingInfo.isPlaying]"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <!-- end ngIf: $first && feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: channel in feed.Channels track by $index -->
  </tbody>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: feed in feedList track by $index -->
  <tbody ng-repeat="feed in feedList track by $index" class="ng-scope" style="
        border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
    ">
    <tr style="
        border: 2px solid pink;
    ">
      <td rowspan="4" title="Lista za Rijeku
    Lista za Rijeku" class="ng-binding" style="
        border: 1px solid black;
    ">
        Lista za Rijeku
        <br>
        <!--</td>
                                    <td rowspan="{{feed.Channels.length + 1}}" title="{{feed.BrandName}}">-->
        Lista za Rijeku
      </td>
      <td class="wrap-text ng-binding" rowspan="4" title="Lisa | casopis " style="
        border: 1px solid blue;
    ">
        Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis
        Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa
        | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis Lisa | casopis
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" ng-attr-title="{{feed.Regions}}
    {{feed.Markets}}" title="
    " style="
        border: 1px solid red;
    ">
        <span class="ng-binding"><br></span>
        <span class="ng-binding"></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" title="Politika
    Izbori" class="ng-binding" style="
        border: 1px solid purple;
    ">
        Politika
        <br>Izbori
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ngRepeat: channel in feed.Channels track by $index -->
    <tr ng-repeat="channel in feed.Channels track by $index" class="ng-scope" style="
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-top: -50px;
    ">
      <td title="Radio antena" class="ng-binding">
        Radio antena
      </td>
      <td class="ng-binding" title="2017-06-22T20:35:45">
        22.6.2017 20:35:45
      </td>
      <!-- ngIf: $first && feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
      <td ng-if="$first &amp;&amp; feedFilter.IncludeMp3" rowspan="3" class="ng-scope">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" ng-click="playPauseSong(feed, $parent.$parent.$index)">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-pause', false: 'glyphicon-play'}[$parent.$parent.$index === player.playingInfo.uiIndentifier &amp;&amp; player.playingInfo.isPlaying]"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <!-- end ngIf: $first && feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: channel in feed.Channels track by $index -->
    <tr ng-repeat="channel in feed.Channels track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <td title="Radio 1" class="ng-binding">
        Radio 1
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" title="2017-06-22T20:21:19" class="ng-binding">
        22.6.2017 20:21:19
      </td>
      <!-- ngIf: $first && feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: channel in feed.Channels track by $index -->
    <tr ng-repeat="channel in feed.Channels track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <td title="Radio Center" class="ng-binding">
        Radio Center
      </td>
      <td title="2017-06-22T18:43:55" class="ng-binding" colspan="2">
        22.6.2017 18:43:55
      </td>
      <!-- ngIf: $first && feedFilter.IncludeMp3 -->
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: channel in feed.Channels track by $index -->
  </tbody>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: feed in feedList track by $index -->
</table>
```

Comment: There seems to be a few things wrong with your html. First, there is more than one <tbody>. Second, you have rowspan="4" but only 3 rows on the "other side"

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for your feedback. I believe that [having more than one tbody is permissible and not in violation with the standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#Usage_notes). And the rowspan is set to 4 because it counts both the rows "on the other side", and the one "on this side" - [that's how it works](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_rowspan.asp).